# Ordenar una lista alfabéticamente con plantillas que recibe un objeto

Tags: c++, string, object, lista

Tengo una lista creada a partir de plantillas la cual recibe un objeto, quisiera ordenar alfabéticamente la lista, la cual guarda "canciones". Tengo esto pero me dice que no puedo convertir un objeto a un char:

```
    template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
    void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::stringSort(){
        float comp;
        T aux;

        for (int i(0); i <= last; ++i) {
            for (int j(i+1); j <= last; ++j) {
                comp=strcmp(data[j],data[j+1]);
                if (comp > 0) {

                    aux=data[j];
                    data[j]=data[i];
                    data[i]=aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

El cpp de mi objeto es la siguiente:

```
    #include "song.h"

    using namespace std;

    Song::Song(){}

    Song::Song(const Song& s) : author(s.author), artist(s.artist), name(s.name), rank(s.rank){ }

    string getAuthor() const;
    void setAuthor(const string &);

    string getArtist() const;
    void setArtist(const string &);

    string getName() const;
    void setName(const string &);

    int getRank() const;
    void setRank(const int &);

    string toString();
    void addSong(Song s);

    string Song::toString(){
        char myRank[7];
        sprintf(myRank, "%d", rank);
        return author + "   |   " + artist + "   |   " + name + "   |   " + myRank;
    }

    Song& Song::operator=(const Song& s) {
        author = s.author;
        artist = s.artist;
        name = s.name;
        rank = s.rank;

        return *this;
    }

    ostream &operator << (ostream &o, Song &s){
       o << "Autor: " << s.getAuthor() << endl
         << "Artista: " << s.getArtist() << endl
         << "Nombre: " << s.getName() << endl
         << "Rango: " << s.getRank() << endl
         << "Archivo a reproducir: " + s.getName() + " - " + s.getArtist() + ".mp3";

       return o;
    }

    istream& operator >> (istream& is, Song& s){
        getline(is, s.author);
        getline(is, s.artist);
        getline(is, s.name);

        string myStr;
        getline(is, myStr) >> s.rank;
        s.rank = atof(myStr.c_str());

        return is;
    }

    bool Song::operator==(const Song& s) {
        if(s.name == name||s.artist == artist||s.rank == rank){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        //return name == s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator!=(const Song& s) {
        return name != s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator<=(const Song&s) {
        return name <= s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator>=(const Song&s) {
        return name >= s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator<(const Song&s) {
        return name < s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator>(const Song&s) {
        return name > s.name;
        }
```

Llamo a la lista así:

```
    List<Song,10> myLista;//La lista
    Song s;//Objeto
```

Me gustaría conseguir que la lista se ordene así:

```
    myLista.stringSort();
```

Clase lista con templates:

```
template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE = 10000>
class List {
private:    
    T data[ARRAYSIZE];
    int last;

    void copyAll(const List&);

    void swapData(T&,T&);

public:
    List();
    List(const List&);

    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();

    void insertData(const int&, const T&);
    void deleteData(const int&);

    int getFirstPos();
    int getLastPos();
    int getPrevPos(const int&);
    int getNextPos(const int&);

    int linearFindData(const T&);
    int binaryFindData(const T &);

    T retrieveData(const int&);

    void bubbleSort();
    void shellSort();
    void insertSort();
    void selectSort();
    void stringSort();
    void quicksort();

    std::string toString();

    void deleteAll();

    List& operator = (const List&);
    T &operator[](int posicion);

};

using namespace std;

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::copyAll(const List<T, ARRAYSIZE>& l) {
    for(int i(0); i <= l.last; i++) {
        data[i] = l.data[i];
    }

    last = l.last;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::List() : last(-1) { }

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::List(const List<T, ARRAYSIZE>& l) {
    copyAll(l);
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
bool List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::isEmpty() {
    return last == -1;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
bool List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::isFull() {
    return last == ARRAYSIZE - 1;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::insertData(const int& p, const T& e) {
    if(isFull()) {
        /// Error, desbordamiento de datos
        throw ListException("desbordamiento de datos, insertData");
    }

    if(p < -1 or p > last) {
        /// Error, posicion invalida
        throw ListException("posicion invalida, insertData");
    }

    int i(last);
    while(i > p) {
        data[i + 1] = data[i];
        i--;
    }

    data[p + 1] = e;

    last++;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::deleteData(const int& p) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        /// Error, insuficiencia de datos
        throw ListException("insuficiencia de datos, deleteData");
    }

    if(p < 0 or p > last) {
        /// Error, posicion invalida
        throw ListException("posicion invalida, deleteData");
    }

    int i(p);
    while(i < last) {
        data[i] = data[i + 1];

        i++;
    }

    last--;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
int List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::getFirstPos() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
int List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::getLastPos() {
    return last;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
int List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::getPrevPos(const int& p) {
    if(isEmpty() or p < 1 or p > last) {
        return -1;
    }

    return p - 1;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
int List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::getNextPos(const int& p) {
    if(isEmpty() or p < 0 or p > last -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return p + 1;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
int List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::linearFindData(const T& e) {
    int i(0);
    while( i<=last){
        if(data[i]==e){
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
    }

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
T &List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::operator[](int posicion)
{

    if (posicion == -1){
        throw out_of_range("-=POSICION INVALIDA=-");
    }
    return data[posicion];
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::swapData(T&a,T&b){
    T aux(a);
    a=b;
    b=aux;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::shellSort() {
    float fact(3.0/4.0);
    int dif(last*fact),i, lim;

    while(dif>0){
        lim=last - dif;
        i=0;
        while(i<=lim){
            if(data[i]>data[i+dif]){
                swapData(data[i],data[i+dif]);
            }
            i++;
        }

        dif*=fact;
    }

}
template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::bubbleSort() {
    int i(last), j;
    bool flag;

        do{
            flag = false;
            j=0;
            while(j<i){
                if(data[j]>data[j+1]){
                    swapData(data[j],data[j+1]);
                    flag = true;
                }
                j++;
            }
        i--;
        }while(flag);
    }
template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::stringSort(){
    float comp;
    T aux;

    for (int i(0); i <= last; ++i) {
        for (int j(i+1); j <= last; ++j) {
            comp=strcmp(data[j],data[j+1]);
            if (comp > 0) {

                aux=data[j];
                data[j]=data[i];
                data[i]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::insertSort() {
    int i(1),j;
    T aux;

    while(i<= last){
        aux=data[i];
        j = i;
        while(j>0 and aux < data[j-1]){
            data[j] = data[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        if(i != j){
            data[j]=aux;
        }

        i++;
        }
    }

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::selectSort() {
    int i(0), j, m;
    while(i<last){
        m = i;
        j = i+1;
        while(j <= last){
            if(data[j]<data[m]){
                m = j;
            }

            j++;
        }

        if(i != m){
            swapData(data[i],data[m]);
        }

        i++;
        }
    }

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
string List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::toString() {
    string result;

    //char myVal[10];

    int i(0);
    while(i <= last) {
        result+= data[i].toString() + "\n";
        /*Para enteros
        sprintf(myVal, "%i",data[i]);

        result += myVal;
        result += "\n";
        */
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::deleteAll() {
    last = -1;
}

template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
List<T, ARRAYSIZE>& List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::operator = (const List<T, ARRAYSIZE>& l) {
    copyAll(l);

    return *this;
}
#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

Gracias por su ayuda gente!

Comment: Así a bote pronto diría que falta la cabecera de `List` y la cabecera de `Song`... para saber qué almacena cada variable (y de qué tipo es) y para conocer la visibilidad de cada miembro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problema.

La función [`std::strcmp`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) pertenece a las librerías de C adaptadas a C++, su firma es:

```
int strcmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs );
```

Es decir, espera recibir dos punteros (de sólo lectura) a `char`, estás llamando a esa función de esta manera:

```
comp=strcmp(data[j],data[j+1]);
```

Hemos visto que `std::strcmp` devuelve un entero (`int`) pero guardas su resultado en un número en coma flotante (`float`), no es un problema grave pues se hace la conversión implícita, pero no tiene absolutamente ningún sentido hacerlo. Tus objetos `data` *supondremos* que son de tipo `Song` por la manera en que instancia tu plantilla:

```
List<Song,10> myLista;//La lista
//   ^^^^ <--- T de la plantilla sera Song
```

Sólo es una conjetura, pues no vemos la definición de tu plantilla. De ser cierta la conjetura le estarías pasando a `std::strcmp` dos objetos de tipo `Song` y hemos visto que espera recibir dos punteros (de sólo lectura) a `char`, de ahí tu error

#### Propuesta.

Suponiendo que quieras comparar las canciones por nombre deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
    comp = strcmp(data[j].getName(), data[j + 1].getName());
```

Eso suponiendo que `Song::getName` devuelva un puntero a `char`<sup>1</sup> si devuelve un `std::string`<sup>2</sup> tendrás que llamar a `std::string::c_str` tras `Song::getName`.

#### No reinventes la rueda.

No tienes ningún motivo para implementar un algoritmo de ordenación, podrías usar el algoritmo de ordenación ([`std::sort`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)) que la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) ofrece. Así pues tu función `List::stringSort` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::stringSort(){
    std::sort(data, data + ARRAYSIZE, [](const T *&a, const T *&b)
    {
        return *a < *b;
    });
}
```

---

1. De ser así, todos los operadores de `Song` estarían mal implementados.
2. En ese caso, era absurdo estar usar `std::strcmp`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo que devuelve el getName, efectivamente son strings. Cómo haría para llamar a std::string::c_str?, puse los getters y setters en el código. El punto de implementar un algoritmo de ordenación es para cumplir con los puntos de una actividad escolar

Comment: Estoy bastante perdido, me sería más sencillo ordenarlo por ranking, pero la actividad me pide que sea por nombre de la canción o nombre del autor, creí con std::strcmp sería suficiente pero ahora veo que no es así. Si intento "data[j].getName()" no puedo ni autocompletar. quizá porque es de un archivo aparte

Comment: No has corregido `List::stringSort`, intenta esto: `comp = strcmp(data[j].getName().c_str(), data[j + 1].getName().c_str());`. De todas maneras, insisto en que abandones tu intento de reinventar la rueda y uses `std::sort`.

Comment: Quiero conseguir eso y te juro que usare std::sort en lo siguiente. Funciona, no diría que ordena pero funciona, si ejecuto varias veces la opción de ordenamiento en cada vez los valores cambian de lugar.

Comment: He intentado con un sort de shell, pero sólo me ordena las primeras tres canciones de 7

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu problema actual ¿podrías aclararlo por favor?

Comment: El problema es que ordena a medias, ordena los primeros 3 elementos y los demás los deja desordenados. https://gyazo.com/8360830c7778ea31cf2071be205d3870

Comment: Tienes mal implementado tu [burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja).